# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning with np.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas data frame that has a column containing a bunch of correlations (all float values). I'm trying to create another column to categorise these correlations into three distinct categories (high/medium/low). I do this using np.where:

```
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Correlation'] >= 0.5, 'high', 
                                   np.where(data['Correlation'] >= 0.3, 'medium','low'))
```

When I try doing this, I always get the **SettingWithCopyWarning** (it seems to work though). I have read up on the difference between copies and views, and even seen recommendations to use .where over other methods to avoid any confusion (and the SettingWithCopyWarning). I still can't quite wrap my head around why I get the warning with this method, can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your *df* has been created as a **view** of another DataFrame,
e.g.:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Correlation': np.arange(0, 1.3, 0.1)})  # Your "initial" DataFrame
df = data.iloc[0:11]
```

Now *df* holds some fragment of *data*, but it uses the data buffer of
*data*.

Then if you attempt to run:

```
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Correlation'] >= 0.5, 'high',
    np.where(df['Correlation'] >= 0.3, 'medium', 'low'))
```

just the mentioned warning occurs.

To get rid of it, create *df* as an **independent** DataFrame, e.g.:

```
df = data.iloc[0:11].copy()
```

Now *df* uses its **own** data buffer and you may do with it whatever
you wish, including adding new columns.

To check whether your *df* uses its own data buffer, run:

```
df._is_view
```

In your original environment (without my correction) you should get
*False*, but after you created *df* using `.copy()` you should get *True*.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with your explanation (also found a typo along the way) and ._is_view will be very useful to understand what's going on when I encounter the warning again in the future. Thank you!